# Use React with a non-browser JS environment

Tags: reactjs

Very open ended, apologies in advance.

I've been going through the docs and searching google incessantly, but I'm wondering what steps I would need to take to use react with a non-browser JavaScript environment.

Some context on the environment:

The environment uses JavaScript to run a UI, it has http capabilities.
There is no html, css, document, window, HTMLElement, etc.

The environment does have the notion of a hierarchy, changes to the object hierarchy in JS cross the bridge and trigger a render through a graphics platform like OpenGL for instance.  The environment does get input via keys and or a mouse.

If there's a roadmap to do this or something like an architecture diagram to refer to, that'd be fantastic.

Any help/advice is appreciated.

thanks in advance,

-dylan

Comment: This would be better suited as a feature request in a [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/new?title=renderComponentToJSON).  It's off topic here.

Comment: Surely there's a set of classes in the react source that can be modified by an engineer to achieve such ends.  Just want to know which classes.

We already have this working but it's all by stubbing out and mocking methods.  We want to get closer to the metal of our engine and do it right.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't make it any less off topic for SO, you'd be better off contacting the React team on github, as was already suggested.

Comment: I remain convinced that in the very near future there will be other JS engineers who will want to use React in a non-browser environment.  Hopefully the SO community will be ready for them.

Answer (score 0):

ReactJS work with DOM, so environment need to have DOM structure, that means no HTML no DOM. Or you can use server render of React component, but you will get a string as result.

Read more here:
[React.renderComponentToString](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponenttostring)